# How do I debug this exception in Xamarin Insights?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios, stack-trace

I have a `SIGABRT` crash in my Xamarin Insights and I don't really know what I can do to find the error.

The title is `SIGABRT Crash in System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw`

This is the stacktrace:

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1 libsystem_c.dylib abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 140
2 MyProject.iOS print_exception (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (runtime.m:782)
3 MyProject.iOS mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mini-exceptions.c:2586)
4 MyProject.iOS mono_handle_exception_internal (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mini-exceptions.c:1573)
5 MyProject.iOS mono_handle_exception (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 40
6 MyProject.iOS mono_arm_throw_exception (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (exceptions-arm64.c:383)
7 MyProject.iOS throw_exception (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 168
8 MyProject.iOS System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 44
9 MyProject.iOS System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__ThrowAsyncm__0_object (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 80
10 MyProject.iOS UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0 (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 40
11 MyProject.iOS Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher:Apply (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 36
12 MyProject.iOS wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 244
13 MyProject.iOS mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mini-runtime.c:2325)
14 MyProject.iOS mono_runtime_invoke (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (object.c:2783)
15 MyProject.iOS native_to_managed_trampoline_1 (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (registrar.m:45)
16 MyProject.iOS -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (registrar.m:2713)
17 Foundation __NSThreadPerformPerform (in Foundation) + 340
18 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 24
19 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation) + 540
20 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 724
21 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384
22 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 180
23 UIKit UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 204
24 MyProject.iOS (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 324
25 MyProject.iOS UIKit.UIApplication:Main (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 44
26 MyProject.iOS UIKit.UIApplication:Main (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 172
27 MyProject.iOS MyProject.iOS.Application:Main (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 36
28 MyProject.iOS wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 244
29 MyProject.iOS mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mini-runtime.c:2325)
30 MyProject.iOS mono_runtime_invoke (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (object.c:2783)
31 MyProject.iOS mono_runtime_exec_main (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (object.c:4038)
32 MyProject.iOS xamarin_main (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (monotouch-main.m:404)
33 MyProject.iOS main (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (main.arm64.m:82)
34 libdyld.dylib start (in libdyld.dylib) + 4
```

So it is my understanding that another thread crashed but I can't find another thread that has useful information.

Some examples of other threads:

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1 MyProject.iOS worker_thread (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threadpool-ms.c:503)
2 MyProject.iOS start_wrapper (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threads.c:723)
3 MyProject.iOS inner_start_thread (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mono-threads-posix.c:97)
4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

and

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib select$DARWIN_EXTSN (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1 MyProject.iOS poll_event_wait (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threadpool-ms-io-poll.c:152)
2 MyProject.iOS selector_thread (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threadpool-ms-io.c:449)
3 MyProject.iOS start_wrapper (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threads.c:723)
4 MyProject.iOS inner_start_thread (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mono-threads-posix.c:97)
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

and

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg_trap (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort (in CoreFoundation) + 196
2 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1032
3 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384
4 WebCore WebCore::runLoaderThread() (in WebCore) + 272
5 JavaScriptCore WTF::threadEntryPoint() (in JavaScriptCore) + 212
6 JavaScriptCore WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() (in JavaScriptCore) + 24
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

and

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1 MyProject.iOS _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (handles.c:1514)
2 MyProject.iOS wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (wait.c:196)
3 MyProject.iOS ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threads.c:1447)
4 MyProject.iOS wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal_System_Threading_WaitHandle_intptr_int_bool (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 128
5 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int_bool (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 124
6 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 44
7 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_Timer_Scheduler_SchedulerThread (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 1260
8 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart_Context_object (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 192
9 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 416
10 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 44
11 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 84
12 MyProject.iOS System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 52
13 MyProject.iOS wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) + 244
14 MyProject.iOS mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mini-runtime.c:2325)
15 MyProject.iOS mono_runtime_invoke (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (object.c:2783)
16 MyProject.iOS start_wrapper (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (threads.c:746)
17 MyProject.iOS inner_start_thread (in 00bc99b261d537d0b6ce6cd2230b0a6d) (mono-threads-posix.c:97)
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

and

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

None of these point to anywhere in my code or to a specific exception that occurred. How am I supposed to debug this?

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45219/stack-trace-not-captured-properly

Comment: @SushiHangover not quite the issue I was having. In that case the topmost stack frame was lost, I don't see how an added frame could exist there.

Comment: Why do you say that this is related to Xamarin *Insights*? I see nothing in any of those stack traces that leads me to suspect anything other than some custom threading code run amuk

Comment: @KeithRome I don't know, it might be the Xamarin Insights that messes up my stacktrace and does not give me the useful information I need. It might be Xamarin itself, or it might be some kind of issue inside Mono. I just want to know if the error reporting can be better than just some random "an async operation failed".

Comment: It's probably an unhandled thread exception, not an async operation failure. Or perhaps an async failure on an unprotected thread. Are you using *any* threading in this app beyond basic async/await? If you are, can you explain the nature of it? That exception being tossed up the stack is probably an AggregateException and thus it's stack trace will originate from the platform's main thread message pump - but the stack trace you want to see is packaged inside of the InnerException[s] of that aggregate.

Comment: @KeithRome I am using a few frameworks that probably have more advanced threading than async/await (I'm thinking network calls, blurring images on other threads). But I should be able to see the `AggregateException` and its inner exceptions, as Xamarin Insights shows the `InnerException` when there is one. I just want to know how I can extract useful information from this crash report.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are talking about. This is an error being reported back to Insights and you are relying on the information in that Insights crash report to diagnose the issue. I (wrongly) interpreted your question to be asking why Insights itself was causing your app to crash. Unfortunately I can't help much on that as I've pulled all Insights integration from our apps until they finish merging it with HockeyApp.

Comment: @KeithRome indeed.

Comment: @KeithRome 
In my case too same thing is happening. The Insights integration code itself is causing the issue.